# Neighbourhood statistics in Google Earth Engine after reclassifying (remap)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to reclassify a categorical raster in Google Earth Engine, and then calculate the proportion of non-0 pixels in a neighbourhood. I've remapped to values of 1 or 0.

I'm having trouble with the `reduceNeighbourhood()` function. With the code below, I expected this to sum the values of all the pixels in the neighbourhood (i.e., sum the 1s), but it doesn't seem to do this? My plan was then to divide this by the number of pixels in the neighbourhood using either a constant (i.e., calculated from my `ee.Kernel.square()` radius) or from `ee.Reducer.count()`.

```js
// import image (image with multiple bands)
var image = ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection3_1/mapbiomas_collection31_integration_v1');

// xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax.
var testArea = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-60,-20,-40,0])

// Get information about the bands as a list.
var bandNames = image.bandNames();
print('Band names: ', bandNames); 

// select single band
var v1985 = image
  .select("classification_1985")
  .clip(testArea);

print(v1985)

// Map.addLayer(v1985)

// do what I want with one image as a trial.
var rc_1985 = v1985.remap([2,3], [1,1],0);

// Map.addLayer(rc_1985)

var k1_1985 = rc_1985.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  kernel: ee.Kernel.square(15, 'pixels')
  });

print(k1_1985)
Map.addLayer(k1_1985)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rc_1985 image is a integer image. The kernel produce a floating value [0-1] image when normalize is true (default). Thus, before applying the reduceNeighbourhood, make sure you 1) cast to a floating value when normalize in the kernel true, 2) set normalize to false. I think the latter is most straightforward:

```
// do what I want with one image as a trial.
var rc_1985 = v1985.remap([2,3], [1,1],0);
// apply the reduce neighbourhood
var k1_1985 = rc_1985.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  kernel: ee.Kernel.square({radius: 15, 
                            units: 'pixels', 
                            normalize: false})
  });
```

The visualization on the map has to do with how GEE handles projection and scale when displaying data to the map; make sure to read the [Projections section](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections) of the Developer Guide.

If you use reproject, which you should use with caution, you will end up with the map you probably expect. However, this is normally automatically done if you specify any scale argument when collecting image statistics (for example in a `reduceRegion` function). You could also export the image to your assets with a defined scale and projection.

```
Map.addLayer(k1_1985.reproject(image.projection()), {min:0, max: 1})
Map.centerObject(testArea, 13)
```

Note that zooming out too much may exceed user memory limits.

In the link to the script, you will see option 1 + an options with the count reducer too. [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/79d7b61a3e3569f4ffa1dcb16a77b927) to the script with three options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't change the result of the calculation. I've exported different stages now (original image, after `remap`, and after `reduceNeighbourhood`) and can see that `ee.Reducer.sum()` within the `reduceNeighborhood` function isn't working as I thought. I want to sum all the pixels (now that I've reclassified as a binary raster) within the kernel. I expected to get integer values ranging from 0 to 900. How can I do that? I can edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Probably this will give some insight in what you are trying: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2fe3bf8c2c2e1efcfe1a36a0bf20ccfa)

Comment: Yes, Thanks for that. It's the  `.toFloat();` that was missing straight after the remap. Also, due to the normalise option in `ee.Kernel.square()` (that's in the manual...) I don't need to divide by the number of pixels in the kernel. So the code above, with the float conversion gives me what I was looking for.  If you include this in your answer I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: Extra question. How did you get the value of 961. Can you show the code for that?

Comment: I'll update the answer. If you apply the `count()` reducer without the `selfmask()`, you will have that value approx, meaning that the aprrox amount of pixels in the new resolution.

Comment: Don't forget the `.toFloat()` after the remap, ie:  `var rc_1985 = v1985  .remap([2,3], [1,1],0).toFloat();`

Comment: If normalize is false, it is not necessary